# How can I get the odoo 17 master password in the ubuntu?

Tags: odoo, odoo-17

I try to install the Odoo 17 via docker compose But I cannot pass through setup screen.

How can I get the odoo master password in the ubuntu.

I want to get the path save the odoo master password, my odoo 17 run on Linux system.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question now: how to install it or where the master password is saved?

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to obtain the master password in Ubuntu?

Comment: It's in the config file, usually in `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I've created setup configs for deploying odoo 17 with docker compose. You may check the [repo](https://github.com/bgunebakan/odoo17-docker-compose).
There is a odoo.conf file to configure master password.